# Integral of a vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:

> $ \int_C(y+\sin x) dx +(z^2+\cos y)dy+(x^3)dz$
>
> Where $C$ is the curve: $c(t) = (\sin t, \cos t, \sin 2t) $. Note that
>   $C$ lies on the surface $z= 2xy$.

**Question:**
Could I just use the parameterization of the surface S $\phi(u,v)=(u, v,2uv) $ with $-1\leq  u\leq 1 $ and $-1\leq v \leq 1$ and use Stokes' Theorem to evaluate $ \int_S \nabla \times  F\cdot dS$ which should be equal to the required integral?

My only trepidation about the above method is that $c(t)$ may not necessarily be on the **boundary** of $S$, which would be required to use Stokes' Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Your instinct to use Stokes's Theorem is a good one. But you need to use the region in that surface whose boundary is $C$, as you understood. Think polar coordinates, since you've got a good start with the parametrization of the curve $C$. Try using $\phi(r,t) = (r\sin t, r\cos t, r^2\sin 2t)$. (Note that this is a parametrization of a region in your surface!) I'll let you figure out the $r$ and $t$ bounds.

Comment: The curve is given in the first place.

Comment: Sure, so of course one could do the integral directly. But applying Stokes's Theorem and taking full advantage of the symmetry in the problem makes for an easy computation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Yes.

Your parametrization is correct.

Now you need to compute the surface normal
$$
\nu = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}.
$$
Applying the Stokes theorem then the surface integral becomes:
$$
\oint_C F\cdot dr =  \iint_S \nabla \times F\cdot dS = \iint_D \nabla \times F\big(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)\big) \cdot \nu/\|\nu\| \,du dv,
$$
where $D = \{u^2 + v^2 \leq 1\}$.

$C$ which is giving by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x = \sin t
\\
&y = \cos t
\\
&z = \sin (2t)
\end{aligned}
$$ assuming $t\in [0,2\pi)$, $C$ lies on $z = 2xy$ simply because the parametrization satisfies the equation of the surface:
$$
z = \sin(2 t) = 2\sin t\cos t = 2xy,
$$
therefore, all the points on $C$, must be on $S$.

The boundary of $S$ is artificial chosen by cut the unbounded surface $z = 2xy$ using the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ (notice the parametrization of the curve also satisfies this), the intersection curve of $z = 2xy$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$ is $C$.

Comment: This is nonsense, I'm sorry. The projection of $C$ on the $xy$-plane is the unit circle $\{x^2+y^2=1\}$, not the boundary of the square $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$. The OP's trepidation was totally well-founded. In addition, one ordinarily refers to the surface normal as the *unit* normal, which this is not. But, when you use the parametrization, this *is* the correct formula for evaluating the surface integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I was being careless.